# Why is this vscode user snippet adding an extra newline?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-snippets

Snippet:

```json
"Create a field with getter and setter" : {
    "prefix": "prop",
    "body": [
        "private ${2:type} ${3:var_name} = ${4:val};",
        "\n",
        "public void set_${3:var_name}(${2:type} ${3:var_name}) {",
        "\tthis.${3:var_name} = ${3:var_name};",
        "}",
        "\n",
        "public ${2:type} get_${3:var_name}() {",
        "\treturn ${3:var_name};",
        "}"
    ]
}
```

result:

```java
private type var_name = val;


public void set_var_name(type var_name) {
    this.var_name = var_name;
}


public type get_var_name() {
    return var_name;
}
```

Expected Output:

```java
private type var_name = val;

public void set_var_name(type var_name) {
    this.var_name = var_name;
}

public type get_var_name() {
    return var_name;
}
```

---

As seen above, an extra newline is getting added after the `\n`. I am new to this, and this is my first user-defined snippet. What exactly have I missed?

Comment: Each line automatically gets a newline.   When you have `"\n"`, you will send a newline, followed by a new line.  If you want single blank line, just use `""`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each line automatically gets a newline.   When you have `"\n"`, you will send a newline, followed by a new line.  If you want single blank line, just use `""`

Answer (score 0):

in case someone wants to have `\n` be parsed as is:

```
\/n
```